# Adding a search bar to webpages generated with Latex2HTML

Tags: latex2html, search

I was wondering whether there is an easy way to add a search bar to (offline) webpages created with LaTeX2HTML, similar to Doxygen (see e.g. [the OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dff/tutorial_cross_referencing.html), where you have a search bar in the top right corner).

The Doxygen solution is quite elegant in the way that you don't need a webserver for it, as [the search itself can be performed by the client](https://doxygen.nl/manual/searching.html).

My current solution is to search the index, but this requires specific keywords to be added manually. Ideally searching would be possible without manual interaction.

Comment: Welcome to tex.x.

Comment: Thank you @barbarabeeton :-)